# Date posting on Fitocracy workout

Tags: fitocracy

I log my workouts on the same day that I do them - part of my post workout ritual.  I've noticed that when I've looked back over the postings that the dates are not the same as the days I logged them (example - last workout was performed & logged on Monday 29 October but is showing 30 October on my fitocracy log...

I'm in the UK - is that a factor?

Answer (score 1):

In October 2013 this was described [here](https://www.facebook.com/Fitocracy/posts/750622431629900) by Oleg Kozitsyn as a bug:

> Oh, another interesting bug: the dates of my newly logged workouts are displayed as one day forward in the feed. Most probably the time zone conversion problem in the displaying script, since I shortly can see the date in ISO 8601 format with correct day, but then it replaced by wrong human-readable one.